# How to save or export tableHTML object in rstudio?

Tags: r, tablehtml

[image]I have written a few line of codes using library(tableHTML). The result is viewed in the viewer, But i am unable to save the same result to a jpg file or any image file. Below i have attached screenshot of my result. the data set which is shown in viewer has to be exported to a image file.

Comment: The docs mention a  function called `tableHTML_to_image`. Have you tried that?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @AllanCameron yes i tried tableHTML_to_image but it throws: Error in add_css_table(., css = list("background-color", "white")) : 
  tableHTML needs to be a tableHTML object.

Comment: @MrFlick Hi i have uploaded my script along with the result in the image. please look into it for our better understanding.

Comment: Please do not share code and data as images. We can't copy/paste that into R to test. See the examples for creating a reproducible example in the link I originally provided.

Comment: @RahulMishra that's because you are trying to save p_summary as an image. According to your code, this is not a tableHTML object. Have you tried `tableHTMLto_image(e1, file = abc, type = "jpeg")` ?